# Sequence in Spark SQL

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a sequence in spark What is the best way to do this?
(In Java)

Like This:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_NUM
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE
CACHE 10
ORDER;
```

Comment: what should the outcome look like?

Comment: Make a number for each line starting from 1 to the last data.
like this:
`1 , 2  , 3 ......`

Answer (score 1):

I think [this is what you want](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html):

> sequence(start, stop, step) - Generates an array of elements from
> start to stop (inclusive), incrementing by step. The type of the
> returned elements is the same as the type of argument expressions.
>
> Supported types are: byte, short, integer, long, date, timestamp.
>
> The start and stop expressions must resolve to the same type. If start
> and stop expressions resolve to the 'date' or 'timestamp' type then
> the step expression must resolve to the 'interval' or 'year-month
> interval' or 'day-time interval' type, otherwise to the same type as
> the start and stop expressions.
>
> Arguments:
>
> start - an expression. The start of the range. stop - an expression.
> The end the range (inclusive). step - an optional expression. The step
> of the range. By default step is 1 if start is less than or equal to
> stop, otherwise -1. For the temporal sequences it's 1 day and -1 day
> respectively. If start is greater than stop then the step must be
> negative, and vice versa. Examples:
>
> ```
> SELECT sequence(1, 5);
>  [1,2,3,4,5]
> SELECT sequence(5, 1);
>  [5,4,3,2,1]
> SELECT sequence(to_date('2018-01-01'), to_date('2018-03-01'), interval 1 month);
>  [2018-01-01,2018-02-01,2018-03-01]
> SELECT sequence(to_date('2018-01-01'), to_date('2018-03-01'), interval '0-1' year to month);
>  [2018-01-01,2018-02-01,2018-03-01]
> ```